# Modal Dialog not showing - PUG

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I am currently working on a simple Modal dialog, that should open on a button press; Figuring I´d use the bootstrap example (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/) as a starter would be the best quick win.

As I am using pug as a view engine, I`ve quickly converted the HTML into Pug and tested it without success.

The Modal Container is not showing / popping up. I don`t get any errors within my console. Bootstrap is functioning perfectly.

The pug code:

```
include modules/head
// Button trigger modal
button.btn.btn-primary(type='button' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#exampleModal')
    | Launch demo modal
// Modal
#exampleModal.modal.fade(tabindex='-1' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true')
    .modal-dialog
        .modal-content
            .modal-header
                h5#exampleModalLabel.modal-title Modal title
                button.btn-close(type='button' data-bs-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close')
            .modal-body
                | This is a test.
            .modal-footer
                button.btn.btn-secondary(type='button' data-bs-dismiss='modal') Close
                button.btn.btn-primary(type='button') Save changes
```

sdsadHead includes both jquery and bootstrap (v4.4).

Does anyone have any ideas why it wouldn`t work?
Suggestions about fade css settings couldnt help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've verified both the JS and CSS for Boostrap are loading correctly?

Comment: Excellent idea. The JS was not working correctly. Thanks @Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed by Sean above the issue was an incorrect load of the Bootstrap.js file.

Fail by developer.